# Missing "!" string when EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

When I enabled DelayedExpansion in the script, it doesn't echo out the "*!*" string in the file name. For instance:

> Original
> File01-TEXT!.txt
>
> Echo out
> File01-TEXT.txt

I guess it's because of the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, but I can't remove because I need it.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd "C:\Files"
for %%a in (*.txt) do (

    REM Here's the problem...
    echo %%a

    set "str=%%a"
    set new_str=!str:0,3!
)

echo %new_string%

pause >nul
```

Comment: Your code is missing the tilde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the real code, you can work with delayed expansion disabled, enable it where access to modified content is needed and then disable again

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    cd "C:\Files"
    for %%a in (*.txt) do (
        set "str=%%a"

        rem Option 1 
        echo file: %%a
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo substring: !str:~0,3!
        endlocal 

        rem Option 2 - capture changed value to use inside non delayed expansion context
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in ("!str:~0,3!") do (
            endlocal
            echo %%a -- %%~b
        )
    )
```

Comment: Works well ! But what does `enableextensions` do here?

Comment: @WhatWhereWhen, Just an habit. Usually, by default, extensions are enabled and you can do substring operations in variables. But sometimes extensions are disabled and code fails. Y automatically type `setlocal enableextensions [disable/enable]delayedexpansion` almost without thinking. Unless there is a reason not to do it, I prefer to explicitly indicate what the code waits.

Comment: @Squashman, AGGG! I should be blind. My fault, thank you. Once corrected, time to repeat a hundred times *"I should not copy/paste"*