# Windows batchfiles - Using exclamation marks within variable values without disabling delayed expansion

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script which replaces several occurrences of a source string within a source text file with a user input string.
For this I use a slightly corrected version of this answer here: [How to replace substrings in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file/20227248#20227248)
(This is not the accepted answer, the accepted one does alter the source file even more!) But I was only able to resolve a little "adds a space to every line"-bug, not the major problem of not being able to use source files with exclamation marks within!

For this remaining problem I researched some more and e.g. found (and tried the suggestions of) these topics:
- [exclamation point being removed constantly in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060943/exclamation-point-being-removed-constantly-in-batch-file)
- [Windows batch - Delayed expansion removes exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370488/windows-batch-delayed-expansion-removes-exclamation-mark)
Sadly these questions' solutions (of temporarily disabling the "delayed expansion") do not apply for me since there is a single line within my script which does need the "delayed expansion" AND has to process variable values with potential exclamation marks!

This is the line
`SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!`
which can be seen in its context following my first link.
As a short explanation: This line needs the delayed expansion to be functional since it resides within an if-else-block within a for-block. On the other hand the value of variable 'string' could contain exclamation marks since it scans through the source file, line by line.

Does anybody has an idea how I could resolve this?

**EDIT:**
According to the first comments I tried to enable the delayed expansions only for the necessary parts of the main loop (only where access to modified variable content is needed, using the "!"-operator). The whole main loop now looks like this:

```
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ('"findstr /n ^^ %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
      SET string=%%A
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%A in ("!string!") do set "string=%%B"
      if  "!string!" == "" (
        echo.>>%OUTTEXTFILE%
      ) else (
        SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
        echo !modified!>> %OUTTEXTFILE%
      )
      endlocal
    )
    endlocal
```

Sadly this yields no benefit at all. This results in the same output file as when I had enabled the delayed expansions for the whole script.
Did I apply the given hints in a wrong way? (If I restrict the enabled range any further, I only get empty lines or other rubbish in the output.)

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I think the simplest one-line solution would be using [JREPL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044).

Comment: One more topic to try [Missing “!” string when EnableDelayedExpansion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33257824/2861476)

Comment: The problem is not such line, but the `SET string=%%A` one, and the solution was posted one answer _below_ your posted one (eichhorn's one) and _also_ one answer below that (AndriyM's one)...

Comment: @ MCND and @Aacini: I tried your suggestions but failed in fixing the problem. I edited my question accordingly. Would you please look into my current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in your edited code.

You are using `findstr/n`, this prefixes each line with a line number and a colon.
But you should avoid the delim set to `¶`, as even it's a uncommon character, it's still a possible character.

Later you try to remove the line number and the colon with

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%A in ("!string!") do set "string=%%B"
```

But this will also remove all leading colons of your input file and destroys also all exclamation marks and sometimes also carets are affected.

Better use

```
set "string=!string:*:=!" Remove all up to the first colon
```

Then both of your echo lines are bad.
`echo.` is slow and can fail.
`echo !variable!` fails when the wrong content is in `variable`

So we end up with

```
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('"findstr /n ^^ %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
  SET "string=%%A"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "string=!string:*:=!"
  if defined string (
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
  )
    (echo(!modified!) >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
  endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The echo line looks a bit odd, but it's more or less simple.
First I enclose a normal echo into a parenthesis block, to ensure that I don't add unwanted spaces to the file, therefor I can add as many spaces after the closing parenthesis, as I want.

```
(echo Sample)    >> myOutputFile.txt
```

But as we need to expand a variable with unknown content, a normal ECHO can't be used here, see this example.

```
set "var1=/?"
set "var2=    "
set "var3=ON"
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
```

But `echo(` works safe with any content. It looks strange but currently there are no side known.

So I simply enclose `echo(!variable!` into parenthesis `(echo(!variable!)`, where only the outer parenthesis build the block, the second opening parenthesis is part of the echo command.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful answer and good explanations so far. Your solution works just like it should. - But could you please elaborate your use of the echo command? I do not know the syntax you are using; I cannot find it within the Microsoft documentation. E.g. what does the extra left parenthesis mean; what are the parentheses around the `!modified!` (and the left out space after `echo`) for (Is this some kind of function call?); why can I use a space character in front of the `>>` in this case without altering the output?